# получить полный URL

Tags: java, rest

подскажите пожалуйста как получит откуда был запрос, т.е. имеется сервис который возвращает время и обращение к этому сервису происходит во всех страницах. выглядит примерно так:

```
@GET
@Path("/getUpdateTime")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public UpdateTime getUpdateTime(@Context HttpServletRequest req) {
    return ut.getLastUpdateTime();
}
```

`req.getRemoteAddr` дает айпи
и т.д. и т.п.
а вот как получит полный адрес откуда был запрос? 
типа `blablabla.ru:8080/qwerty/asd.html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно Вы имели в виду **REFERRER**

> Referer является одним из заголовков запроса клиента. Содержит URL
>   источника запроса. Если перейти с одной страницы на другую, referer
>   будет содержать адрес первой страницы. ... Если HTTP-клиент загружает
>   с сервера картинку, представленную на какой-либо странице, то referer
>   будет содержать адрес этой страницы.
>
> *(c) Wikipedia*

Его можно получить запросив из объекта запроса соответствующий заголовок:

```
String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");
```

Однако, я не вижу как это может быть связано со временем?
Может быть Вам просто стоит вначале обработчика создавать объект даты с текущим временем и позже его выводить?

Comment: `String referrer = request.getHeader("referer");` это помогло... спасибо
там время последнего обновления данных хранится вот его и извлекаю из базы..

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getCurrentUrl(HttpServletRequest request){
    URL url = new URL(request.getRequestURL().toString());
    String host  = url.getHost();
    String userInfo = url.getUserInfo();
    String scheme = url.getProtocol();
    String port = url.getPort();
    String path = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri");
    String query = request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.query_string");

    URI uri = new URI(scheme,userInfo,host,port,path,query,null)
        return uri.toString();
}
```

На основе примера выше, Вы можете составить адрес в удобном для Вас формате

Comment: спасибо за ответ но это не совсем правильное решение, т.к. сервис вызванивается аджаксом
`$.ajax({
            url: "updatetime/getUpdateTime", 
            success: function (data) {`

и по вашему коду я всегда получу `blablabla.../updatetime/getUpdateTime`